# solr version 4.1 PostingsSolrHighlighter feature not works

Tags: solr, highlighting, solr-query-syntax

Now am doing analyzing on solr 4.1 version .In which,new Feature ***"SOLR-4271: Add support for PostingsHighlighter."*** has been given.

From the following link, **http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/highlight/PostingsSolrHighlighter.html** I found how to configure PostingHighlighter.

So I configured my PostingHighLighter as follows,

```
 < searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
 < highlighting class="org.apache.solr.highlight.PostingsSolrHighlighter"
                  preTag="&lt;em_testing&gt;"
                  postTag="&lt;/em_testing&gt;"
                  ellipsis="... "
                    />
 < /searchComponent>
```

I used the following query to test highlighter;

***solr/collection1/query?q=electronics&shard.keys=customerB!&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=cat***

But my result was, following one
< lst name="highlighting">

< lst name="F8V7067-APL-KIT">

< arr name="cat">

< str>

< em>electronics< /em>

< /str>

< /arr>

The expected result is < em_testing> instead of < em>.

So Whats wrong with my configuration or what is the actual use of PostingSolrHighlighter.